# Causes for NaN in C++ application that do no raise a floating point exception

Tags: c++, nan, floating-point-exceptions

To find the cause of floating point variables beeing set to NaN in my C++ program I enabled floating point exceptions like this:

```
#include <fenv.h>
feenableexcept(FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW);
```

I know it works because when I write:

```
int val = 0.0/0.0;
```

in my program a floating point exception is risen.
But NaNs are "spreading" through the floating point calculations of my program and I have no idea which variable is set to NaN first.

What causes for a variable beeing set to NaN exist, that would not cause a floating point exception?

Comment: When adding **FE_UNDERFLOW** I get lots of exceptions where I am multiplying by 0. Can an underflow really cause a NaN?

Comment: @Nathan Are you sure you aren't actually multiplying by a very small number close to zero?

Comment: @Nathan: As far as I read it, yes. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Comment: @Nathan: An alternate way of tracking this down would be to make an `isNaN` function and start littering your code with `assert(!isNaN(x))`

Comment: @Nathan @Erik Just to be explicit, here's how you can write isNaN: template<typename T> bool isNaN(T value) { return value != value; }

Comment: @Erik. Looking on [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) the only thing about underflow is this: _a result is very small (outside the normal range)_ and is inexact. That does not cause a NaN, does it? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Erik, @SuperEletric Yes, littering with isNaN tests is a possibility. That's what I am doing so far. It is very annoying that is why I am searching for an alternative.

Comment: @Nathan: IIRC there's a FE_ALL flag, doubt it'd help much if you get exceptions for underflow already though.

Comment: Underflow cannot generate a NaN.

Comment: Underflows and overflows can, however, generate `inf`s and `0`s, which can quickly lead to `NaN`s.

Answer (score 7):

If any input has a quiet NaN value, it will cause the result of nearly any floating-point operation that consumes it to be NaN **without raising the invalid exception**.

The most likely explanation is that some data is being read from the wrong address, and that the read data (which may not even be floating-point data) happens to match a quiet NaN encoding.  This can happen pretty easily, because the relatively common pattern `0xffff...` encodes a quiet NaN.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing any square root operation? If you try to compute a square root for a negative number as in sqrt(-1) then you will get a Nan. In this case you should get an 'Invalid Operation' exception though. Are you sure you are trapping correctly all exceptions? It seems like a numeric exception is untrapped somewhere in your code.